# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code: react native

Tags: react-native

Can someone please help me to understand why this error is coming up?
When i tried to run npx react-native run-ios.
With react native version 0.65.0 in my macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.5
I have also attached the error when i tried with xcode version 13.2.1

Error shown in cmd

[image: 1]

and

Error shown in xcode version 13.2.1

[image: 2]

Comment: Please check this answer I had similar issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31249#issuecomment-811715288

Comment: thanks for the reply. I down graded my react native version to 0.65 and it worked.